# Generating random numbers from a multiplication of CDFs

Tags: random-variable, random-generation, cumulative-distribution-function

I am interested in the following problem - 
Suppose I have $X_1, \dots, X_n$ independent random variables, with CDFs $F_1, \dots ,F_n$ accordingly (i.e $X_i$ has CDF $F_i$). In addition, let's suppose that it is easy to sample from each $F_i$.
What is the simplest way to generate, say 100, independent random numbers from the distribution $G(x) = F_1(x)\cdots F_n(x)$?

I'm thinking about Accept-Reject algorithm.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Simplest" depends on the relative costs of generating random variates from the $F_i$ and computing the $F_i$ themselves.  For instance, sometimes *the only* feasible approach is to generate the variates--the $F_i$ aren't even mathematically given--and take their maximum.  At other times the $F_i$ might be remarkably easy and fast to compute, which could permit other solutions.

Comment: @whuber If we assume access to cheap pointwise evaluations of $F_i$s and more costly random sampling from the $F_i$s (but not, say, performing simplifying analytical manipulations), is there some (somewhat) generally more efficient method than taking-maximum-of-variates? If so, I suggest posting as an answer.

Comment: @Juho Numeric inversion of the product immediately comes to mind.  Other solutions might be possible depending on the analytical form taken by the product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the $X_i$s are independent, $G(x)$ is the CDF of the maximum of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, since
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\max ( X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1, \leq x, X_2\leq x \ldots, X_n \leq x) \\ = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x)\,\mathbb{P}(X_2 \leq x)\,\ldots\,\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq x) = F_1(x)\,F_2(x)\,\ldots\,F_n(x).
\end{equation}
Thus, a realization from the distribution $G$ may be generated by simulating independent realizations from all $F_i$s   and taking the maximum.  100 independent random numbers may be generated by repeating this 100 times.

More efficient (using less random variables) sampling may be attainable in special cases (such as if $G$ itself has an easy-to-sample-from form), but assuming only the premises of the question, I don't see how there could be any better method than taking the maximum.

Comment: \ldots ... would look nicer :-)